# Fazer um INNER JOIN utilizando o IF

Tags: sql, select, if

Eu estou fazendo um INNER JOIN da Tabela Combo com a Tabela Combo Produto como mostro abaixo...

```
    SELECT C.SchoolID, C.ComboID, P.Active, P.Name, P.ProductID
    FROM sales.Combo AS C
    INNER JOIN commons.Stock AS S ON C.SchoolID = S.SchoolID AND C.ProductID = S.ProductID 
    INNER JOIN commons.Product AS P ON C.SchoolID = P.SchoolID AND C.ProductID = P.ProductID
    WHERE        (C.SchoolID = 01)
```

Ela me retorna por exemplo os seguintes valores:

---

```
SchoolID___|ComboID___|Active___|Produto

01_________|01________|True______|01

01_________|01________|False_____|02

01_________|02________|True______|01

01_________|02________|True______|05
```

Eu estou tentando modificar essa minha Query para que se 1 dos produtos do Combo estiver como Active = False ele não selecione o ComboID que tenha esse produto = false

Eu tentei usar o IF mas não obtive sucesso...

Comment: Você não poderia adicionar no "AND Active IS TRUE" ?

Comment: Se eu adicionar "AND Active IS TRUE" ele vai continuar selecionando o Combo porque o outro produto do Combo esta como "TRUE".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma das formas de solucionar este caso, é utilizar uma View/Subselect:

```
SELECT C.SchoolID, C.ComboID, P.Active, P.Name, P.ProductID
    FROM sales.Combo AS C
    INNER JOIN commons.Stock AS S ON C.SchoolID = S.SchoolID AND C.ProductID = S.ProductID 
    INNER JOIN commons.Product AS P ON C.SchoolID = P.SchoolID AND C.ProductID = P.ProductID
    WHERE        (C.SchoolID = 01) 
     AND C.COMBOID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT C.COMBOID FROM sales.Combo AS C
     INNER JOIN commons.Stock AS S ON C.SchoolID = S.SchoolID AND C.ProductID =  S.ProductID
     INNER JOIN commons.Product AS P ON C.SchoolID = P.SchoolID AND C.ProductID = P.ProductID
     WHERE (C.SchoolID = 01) AND (P.ACTIVE = FALSE))
```

Comment: Deu certo assim! Vlw...